# C# Nested Reflection SetValue with IDictionary

Tags: c#, reflection

How do you set a value of a nested object? Here are my classes:

```
public class MyPage<MyData> { 
    public MyData Content {get;set;}
}

public class MyData { 
    public IDictionary<string, string> Text { get;set; }
}
```

I have an expression represented as a string as follows

```
var expressionString = "Content[\"Main\"]";
```

The value to set

```
var value = "hello world!";
```

The object to set

```
var page = new MyPage<MyData>();
```

Please note that Content is null and Text is null. I would like to create the while setting Text["Main"] = "hello world!";

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your current code and tell us what is not working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can work, you have to initialize everything to get it to work.  To use those classes you need to do the following:

```
MyPage<MyData> myPage = new MyPage<MyData>();
myPage.Content = new MyData();
myPage.Content.Text = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myPage.Content.Text["foo"] = "bar";
myPage.Content.Text["fizz"] = "buzz";

foreach (var item in myPage.Content.Text)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Key + item.Value);
}
```

What you probably want to do is change your classes to do the following.  This way all of your objects are already initialized when you create your MyPage class.  Also I don't see a need for adding  to MyPage since you are limiting it to  anyway.

```
public class MyPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        Content = new MyData();
    }
    public MyData Content { get; set; }
}

public class MyData
{
    public MyData()
    {
        Text = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Text { get; private set; }
}
```